# How to remove one type of files (raw photos) from folder structure?

Tags: automation, delete-file, storing-data, photography

I'm an amateur photographer and I have a problem with storing my files.

I have a drive (actually 2 hard drives for safety reasons) where I keep all of my personal photos. It's simple structure: year -> date -> raw, jpg (straight from camera/phone), edited (if I edited and exported any raws). After owning better quality camera for a few years the size of all of this is getting huge so I'd like to delete all raw files (I hope I won't need them after a few years. These aren't paid projecs. Just me, my family, friends, landscapes, etc.). Of course I have to automate that :) What's the best way to do it?

Additionally it'd be awesome if I could also automaticaly lower a bit the quality of 20mb jpgs to get some more free space. Is it possible to do that in photoshop while maintaining folder structure?

If you have any tips for storing photos, let me know!

Thanks in advance!
Kacper

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Explorer, or similar, sort all of the files in the folder by clicking on the File Type Header.
It's easy to then select the files that have raw extensions and delete them. If you want to do this for all subfolders, select the relevant folder (e.g. D: or[1] D:\Photos) then type *.RAW where RAW is your raw files' extension. Press return to see a list of every raw file.

[RAW Files list generated by Search]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/70LpE.png